# grub-mkconfig error "wrong argument" count

Tags: debian, grub2

I just updated my kernel to 6.1 after uplifting Debian 11 to 12. Using `grub-customiser`, I pushed the 6.1 entry to the top of the menu and saved.

While doing this though, something went wrong and customizer exited without any error message.

Trying to restart it to check if the changes were applied, I encountered following error:

[image: Picture of the error in grub-customizer]

I have some familiarity, having switched from Windows just 2 months ago, so I ran `grub-mkconfig` in the terminal to try to identify the issue.

Based on my findings, it seems that the problem lies within the script itself rather than the arguments passed when invoking the command. Since I haven't used bash extensively yet, I didn't want to modify the `mkconfig` script directly.

I'm reaching out here to seek advice on how to resolve this issue or any mistakes I might have made due to my limited understanding of Linux and its internal mechanisms.

**UPDATE:**
I managed to resolve the issue by purging grub2-common and manually removing the content of `/etc/grub.d`, then reinstalling grub2-common.
However, I also managed to recreate it, by simply running `sudo grub-customizer` and saving within the GUI, even without making any changes to the config. "grub-customizer" responds with an error "failed to write to configuration file". After that, running `sudo grub-mkconfig` and restarting "grub-customizer" fails. Might this be a case for a bug report on the projects GitHub?

Comment: What version of GRUB do you have and what is the full command (with arguments) you use to run `grub-mkconfig`?

Comment: @memchr I am using grub 2.06-13 and ran the command as stated in the man/info page "sudo grub-mkconfig -o someoutputfile" and it gave me the error with the invalid argument count and that I have to pass the config as arg 1

Comment: By now I fixed the issue by using brute force, aka. purging grub2 and manually removing all the content of ```/etc/grub.d```, then reinstalling grub2-common. I want to know, what caused this though, since it happened again, after I used grub-customizer. Might it be an issue with that thing messing up some configs?

Comment: That "I/O error" doesn't look very good.

Comment: @IporSircer Right? But where does all this come from? I can't find any mention of a grub-customizer bug or anything similar on the web.